# Check for checkboxes in form and get attribute instead if value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I have a form which is saved to Local Storage as a String. My form however has few checkboxes, radio buttons and so on that use `attribute` instead of `value`. How can I perform such a check and pass on right "values" to the Local Storage in my dataSave function?

```
function dataSave(){
   var mngrFields = {};
   $(".mngr-field").each(function(){
      if ($(".mngr-field").is("checkbox")){
         mngrFields[this.id] = this.attr("checked");
      } else {
         // Default method to get input-text values
         mngrFields[this.id] = this.value;
      }
   });
   localStorage.setItem('fieldString', JSON.stringify(mngrFields));
}
```

The **default method to get input-text values** is working just fine on it's own, but when the checkbox checker is included, it breaks the whole application because of an error.

Any ideas on how can I build up a good checker that I might be able to use for radio buttons as well?

Comment: What is the exact error? And can you add in your question part of the HTML with these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general all you need to do is just to check the type of input fields and to detect `checked` attribute for radio and checkbox ones - both of them have `true/false` for it. Here is the example with all basic HTML types:

```
<input class="mngr-field" type="radio" id="field-01" checked> Checked radio<br>
<input class="mngr-field" type="radio" id="field-02"> Unchecked radio<br>
<input class="mngr-field" type="checkbox" id="field-03" checked> Checked checkbox<br>
<input class="mngr-field" type="text" id="field-04"> Comment on how it went?<br>
<select class="mngr-field" id="field-05">
    <option value="">Rate</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select> Rate it<br>
<textarea class="mngr-field" id="field-06">Area text</textarea><br>
<input type="button" value="Save to LS" onclick="dataSave()">
<script>
    function dataSave() {
        var mngrFields = {};
        $('.mngr-field').each(function () {
            if(this.type == 'radio' || this.type =='checkbox')
                mngrFields[this.id] = this.checked;
            else
                mngrFields[this.id] = this.value;
        });
        localStorage.setItem('fieldString', JSON.stringify(mngrFields));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString')));
    }
</script>
```

Console log output:

```
Object {field-01: true, field-02: false, field-03: true, field-04: "Input text", field-05: "2", "field-06":"Area text"}
    field-01: true
    field-02: false
    field-03: true
    field-04: "Input text"
    field-05: "2"
    field-06: "Area text"
```

I'm sure you know how to proceed with localStorage string after that. :)

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm! Would've thought this was way more complicated, but seems like not. Thank you, again! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this line `if ($(".mngr-field").is("checkbox")){` is the culprit. jQuery `is` checks for the conformance of an element with a selector, and `"checkbox"` does not seem to be a valid selector for a checkbox. Try `if ($(".mngr-field").is(":checkbox")){` instead.